# Error: database or disk is full (code 13 SQLITE_FULL) because of too big AWS DynamoDb Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, datastore, asyncstorage

I encountered this Error while working on a react native app:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Array [
  [Error: database or disk is full (code 13 SQLITE_FULL)],
]
```

I came across a relevant article where someone faced a similar issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8640. After some investigation, I suspect this rejection is related to AsyncStorage due to a limitation of 6MB for the database in Android devices. My iOS device is running the app without any errors.

The problem seems to be connected to a table in my DynamoDB, which I'm accessing using AWS Amplify DataStore. This specific table is about 15MB in size:

[image: table]

Now I lack on understanding why this is happening.The data is stored in my DynamoDb and I only query for single table entries or do a simple save (DataStore.query or DataStore.save) Example:

```
     const getTypeForId = async (typeId) => {
    try {
      const type = await DataStore.query(CarType, (carType) =>
        carType.carTypeId.eq(typeId)
      );
      setSelectedCarType(type[0]);
    } catch {
      console.log("No Type for Id");
    }
  };
```

So how is my ASyncStorage on my virtual Android device filling up completely?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exception produced by DynamoDB, it's coming from something within the device itself by utilising local storage of some sort. For example, if you are using DynamoDB Local or some other form of local storage.

Here is the official SQLITE docs on the exception: https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#full

Comment: Upon deleting most of the content from the 15MB DynamoDB table, leaving only 5 entries, the error no longer occurs. This finding strongly suggests that the error is indeed related to the size of the table. I also dont use DynamoDB Local or another form of local storage.

Comment: I promise you DynamoDB is not telling you that you've too much data, there is no upper bound to how much data you store. Moreover, DynamoDB does not use SQLite which is the source of your exception.

Comment: You may be using temporary directories after reading the data, so reducing the amount of data you read and temporarily store is avoiding the error.

Comment: Yes Im sure that DynamoDB isn’t the problem. But I query as stated with Datastore.query for a entry with a specific ID. So there shouldn’t be a large amount of data temporary stored because I access only 1 element…

Comment: I suggest debugging your storage in Android Studio, just to understand what it's being filled up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android try increasing the largeHeap.
You can add below to your AndroidManifest.xml - application element